# UWP App always exits with non-zero return code

Tags: c#, uwp, destructor

To my understanding, an application that doesn't finish and return with a 0 error code didn't terminate correctly. Somehow though, any UWP App I make, even the very default one, finishes with error code 1 every single time. Moreover, it's main class's `Dispose()` and destructor are never called. Is this expected behaviour?

To reproduce, I just made the default UWP app:

- *Right click on Solution -> Add -> New Project...*
- Then under *Other Languages -> Visual C# -> Windows Universal -> "Blank App (Universal Windows)"*
- Then Build and Deploy the app.

If you now run and then close the app, it seems like it's being force-quit. The last output I get is:

```
The thread 0x35a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x34f4 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[3376] App1.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

So I take this to mean that a thread fails, and then that fails the application. Is this correct, and is this bad?

Moreover, I added the following code to the main `App.xaml.cs`:

```
    ~App()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Calling destructor");
    }

    // (Implement Disposable interface)
    public void Dispose() 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Calling dispose");
    }
```

Neither is ever called. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you to play with UWP [lifecycles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) and events. As far as my understanding goes, The application when closed by the user go to the ***suspended*** mode and then it is ***terminated***.
The UWP application lifecycle goes through a series of steps wherein it even **enters** and leaves the **background** while at start or **suspend**.
In **App.Xaml.Cs** you can go ahead any play with the events and understand how the application lifecycle works.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps to create a blank project. Running it gave me: 
[image]

Neither the thread or the application closed with a exit code. So what you are experiencing is not normal and is considered a problem especially if the thread is terminating the whole application. I would uninstall VS17 and any libraries and then do a clean install.

Have you tried a non-UWP project template?

Comment: Thanks for trying, ok that seems bad indeed then and maybe my install or OS is the issue. Was this a UWP GUI app, like, the one that initialises a WPF MainWindow?

Comment: Yes, I created one from the VS template just as you did. I would try reinstalling VS and making sure your libraries are all fresh before you look into your OS. Most likely culprit is the VS install.